# What happens if your answer is converted into a comment?

Tags: discussion, penalty

My understanding is that if your answer is deleted by a moderator, there is penalty (at least one that may count toward an answer ban).

What happens if your answer gets converted into a comment by a moderator? That is, it is considered "constructive," but not in the form of an answer. Is there still a penalty, and if so, is it less than if the comment were totally deleted?

Answer (score 20):

For most people, this is a non-issue, but in principle as far as the answer ban is concerned, there's no difference between answers that were converted to comments and answers that were deleted for any other reason.

Comment: How about a question that was successfully migrated from Site A to Site B here at SE. Is there, say, a question ban penalty on site A?

Comment: @TomAu Migrated questions can count towards the question limit, yes. How they affect it depends on the type of limiting that's enabled on the source site.

Comment: So it varies from site to site?

Comment: @TomAu Potentially. I believe every site has the rolling limits enabled now, some also have the old-school question block.