# Can < 50 rep users whose answers were converted to comments make comments?

Tags: feature-request, support, comments

Often a user who does not have comment privileges will post a comment as an answer instead.

Usually when I see this I flag NAA except in the case where the comment is actually particularly useful, in which case I raise a mod flag requesting that the answer (and relevant parts of its discussion) be converted to question comments. Most of the time these flags are honored.

My question is: If a user without enough rep to comment has their answer converted to comments on a question (and they are not the author of the question), can they then add new comments to that question, despite not having the comment privileges?

If not, then this also doubles as a feature request: Can the rules about who can comment on a post be extended to let this be the case? While I wholeheartedly endorse the usual advice of "contribute, then you will be able to comment", *occasionally* a brand new user leaves a valuable comment as an answer, where further discussion is constructive and worthwhile and so it is converted to a comment, and in these cases I'd like to be able to both properly handle the NAA aspect of it immediately, but let the conversation continue at the same time.

Comment: actually, that feels like it makes a lot of sense.  And I haven't a clue, or a sub 50 rep sock...

Comment: I have just created an account here, therefore I have less than 50 rep. Could you convert this "answer" to a comment so I could try to comment on myself?

Comment: No, the privilege does not pay any attention to whether they already have a comment. Posting an answer only gives them the inherent right to comment *on their answer*. They never gain the privilege to comment on the question without the required reputation.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, no. SE employee **animuson** ♦ [said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295437/can-50-rep-users-whose-answers-were-converted-to-comments-make-comments#comment958519_295437):

> No, the privilege does not pay any attention to whether they already have a comment. Posting an answer only gives them the inherent right to comment *on their answer*. They never gain the privilege to comment on the question without the required reputation.

In my humble opinion, this feature you request is not so good. If this is allowed, more and more users will start posting "valuable" comments in answer boxes, thus minimizing their need to write a good answer. I say, things are good as it is now.

Comment: *"more and more users..."* -- I am not sure why that would be the case. Users can already do this, and if they post poor answers, they'd just get downvoted / answer banned. If they post good answers and end up with 50 rep then none of this applies. Plus this is exceedingly rare, there's not really an opportunity for a new user to be aware this is a pattern, let alone develop a habit of doing it. If their comment answers are so good that enough of them are converted to comments for them to notice a pattern, I highly doubt they won't soon post an answer that gets +5 or more.

Comment: Still +1 for the answer part of this.

Comment: @JasonC Well, that makes sense. But I still don't see why we need a new feature. Such (mostly unregistered) new users who post valuable comments in answers probably won't return to post again. So having theirs converted to comments or not, they won't notice.

Answer (score 1):

Its not *explicitly stated so* , but [the appropriate help page says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)

> Please note that you can always comment on your own posts, and any part of your questions. However, commenting on other people's posts is a privilege.

Implicitly suggests its not the case. It makes sense though.

Lets assume I'm a low reputation user who's got no idea how things work here - I come in and post something assuming the traditional threaded discussion board system. In theory, we're interested in (at least temporarily) keeping some constructive comment posted as a question around. On the other hand, letting you comment basically gives any user with under 50 reputation with a converted comments, full commenting rights to the post.

(Also, its probably easier to check if someone 'owns' a post, rather than to check through everyone who has ever commented).

On the other hand, its *confusing* to someone who doesn't quite get the Q&A model,  so maybe it would be nice to pop them a little notification when they try to post *another* answer to a question with a converted answer to comment, reminding them that an answer's an answer and not a place for comments

Comment: I see what you mean about a single confused user potentially continuing to do that on the same post. A pop-up would be a good addition if this were to be implemented. Do answer deletions / comment conversions by mods contribute to answer bans? (Btw, on the other other hand, currently if a new user has an answer converted to a comment, they'd be *forced* to post yet another comment answer if they wanted to reply. So I wonder if it sort of... cancels out a potential confusion effect of letting them comment, no net change in behaviors.)

Comment: I *think* so.  I'll need to go down the meta/help rabbit hole to be sure.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238903/what-happens-if-your-answer-is-converted-into-a-comment/238905#238905 No difference at all it seems.

Comment: Nice digging. That's a plus here, too, then, as a layer of protection against an eternally confused user.